# Is Deism in Christianity possible? If so, what does it look like?

Tags: christology, deism

In short, Deism is more or less that God exists but has not really an interaction with humanity. He just gave a set of natural laws by which he governs people.

Now, Jesus came to Earth as the incarnated God ascended from above, so by this there seems to be a direct interaction between God and human kind. Does this mean that Deism isn't really possible in Christianity even though in the 18th Century it developed within Christian countries?

Was this perhaps more about God and not so much with Jesus involved?

If it can exist how was/is this argued?

I'm not sure is any denomination has a particular view on this, but if necessary the vision of the RCC would be welcome.

Comment: A couple of possibilities: You could assert that Jesus was not God Incarnate. You could assert that he was God Incarnate, but, except those 33 years, God does not directly interact with the world. Either could lead to Deism and are comparable with C.SE's definition of Christianity.

Comment: I don't think you need to include the last sentence for this particular question.  Deism is _not_ compatible with Catholicism.  I think there might be too much to answer here if you want answers both positive and negative towards deism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Catholicism Share Some Beliefs with Deism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36806/does-catholicism-share-some-beliefs-with-deism)

Comment: See [Christian deism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_deism) on Wikipedia.

Comment: "Is deism compatible with Christianity?" would first be very opinion based, then too philosophical, rather than being about Christianity and how it is practiced.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, Deism cannot be reconciled with Christianity; they are 2 very different theological philosophies.

Deism is a metaphysical philosophy which acknowledges the existence of a single God who has served and continues to serve as the indispensable foundation for existence or perhaps as the Origin of Existence.  The Deistic God is outside the realm of physical and specifically, human activity and is therefore impersonal, as well as lacking the characteristics of personification.  (Even referring to the Deistic God, as "He", is actually incorrect and instead, the use of the word, "It", is more consistent with its true definition and meaning).  I would argue that Deism probably has a much closer intellectual connection with Aristotle's, "Metaphysics" than with the Christian God-(or Theism in general).

(Note: I am a member of the History Stack Exchange).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Comment: You should review [c.se's definition of who is a Christian](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/880/who-is-a-christian-for-this-site). With that definition there are several forms of Christianity that are compatible with Deism.

Answer (score 0):

Deism certainly has the ability to be compatible with the moral teachings of Jesus.  A Deist could welcome the moral philosophy of Jesus, while also remain detached from the metaphysical nature of Christianity.  This type of so-called "Christian Deism" was discussed by John Locke and especially Thomas Jefferson.

Comment: This answer would greatly benefit from some references supporting its statements. See: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/20394)

Comment: I think I understand why you answered twice.  But I don't think you need two separate answers on this question.  Christianity is full of paradoxes, so it's OK to answer yes and no in the same answer.