# Do some deists believe in Resurrection of Christ?

Tags: christology, resurrection-of-jesus, deism

I once met one guy on Youtube who says he believes that Jesus was so moraly perfect (secular language to say sinless) that He got attention of the Supreme Being (i.e. God) and that this Supreme Being adopted Jesus as His own Son on baptism and filled Him with supernatural power, explaining Jesus's miracles. He also thinks God did raised Jesus from the dead, but this was simply the reward for Jesus's perfectness and Christ's ascension to heaven was simply reward for Jesus to be ascended to the spiritual realm where God resides.

That's all he believes. He doesn't think Original Sin is true, he doesn't think Exodus happened (the way it is described in the Bible), he doesn't believe in pre-existence of Christ, not in virgin birth, Atonement of Christ or Second Coming.
He thinks that Jesus was mistaken about promises of Second Coming because He confused God with Yahweh He worshipped as a Jew and thought Kingdom will be set with Him as the Messiah. After Resurrection, Christ knew that Yahweh and the Father are not the same God (according to this Christian deist). This deist also considers Gospel of Mark as ONLY reliable, he rejects other three Gospels. He doesn't worship Jesus or pray to Him, he isn't part of any denomination, he is very liberal, he is okay with homosexuality and etc.

I wonder, are there any other deists who think Christ historically rose from the dead?

Comment: Given there are zero watchers and only four questions on the subject of deism here on the Christianity Stack site, it is unlikely your question will attract much attention, let alone a response from a deist. I have edited your tags to delete Eastern Orthodox (why did you put that one in?) and include deism.  Please take our tour: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour  This is how we are different from other sites: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because deism isn't a type of Christianity.

Comment: I think I'll vote to close as well. My understanding of Deism is that it is a vague collection of various beliefs, and some are distinctly not of Christianity.

Comment: Deisim is a tag within Christianity Stack. Surely it is a subject that Christians can address when questions are asked about it?

Comment: @Lesley It's a tag that's only been used a few times, mostly in a comparative religion way, similar to how we have questions comparing Christianity and Islam. But questions purely about deism and not about Christianity shouldn't be on-topic here.

Comment: @curiousdannii Do some deists believe in Resurrection of Christ? And are there any other deists who think Christ historically rose from the dead?  Isn’t that about Christianity?

Comment: @Lesley I don't know for certain but I wouldn't expect so, seeing as deists don't believe the creator god intervenes in the world at all after creating it.

Answer (score 4):

“Christian deist” is a contradiction in terms.  Christians believe in the pre-incarnate existence of Jesus as the eternal and uncreated Word of God who was with God in the beginning and who is God.  “The Word became flesh and dwelt with us” (John 1:1-3; 14).  Deists reject any notion that Jesus pre-existed before he was born.

Christians also believe in the miraculous virgin birth, that the Holy Spirit was the means by which Mary was impregnated – that no man was involved.  Deists reject the virgin birth.

Christians believe that Jesus gave up his life in order to pay for the sin of the world and that it is only by repenting of our sins and coming to saving faith in what Jesus did that we can be forgiven.  Deists reject any notion of sin, repentance and salvation through the death and resurrection of Jesus.

Christians believe that the resurrected and glorified Jesus will return to judge the world and establish the Kingdom of God on Earth.  The enemies of God (the powers of sin and darkness) will be destroyed in the final battle and then God will establish a new heaven and a new earth.  Deists do not.

This deist might believe in the resurrection of Jesus but from what you’ve said, their view of who Jesus is bears little resemblance to the biblical and Christian beliefs concerning Jesus Christ.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deism

[Does Catholicism Share Some Beliefs with Deism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36806/does-catholicism-share-some-beliefs-with-deism?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Is Deism in Christianity possible? If so, what does it look like?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60406/is-deism-in-christianity-possible-if-so-what-does-it-look-like)

Comment: I prefer pre-incarnate to 'pre-mortal' and I do not find 'atone for the sins of the world' anywhere in my bible. 'Sin of the world' yes. And I also understand that there will be 'new heavens and a new earth' for the 'planet' will not and cannot, in righteousness, continue. Nor will it revolve round a sun for there shall be no need of such a thing. So 'planet' may be altogether wrong and we might be better to stay with 'earth'. But +1 nevertheless.

Comment: Since there have been many people generally thought of as Deists who described themselves as Christians (including several Founding Fathers of the United States), it may difficult to be so insistent that  *“Christian deist” is a contradiction in terms*, especially on a site with a [broad definition of Christian](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/880/who-is-a-christian-for-this-site)

Comment: @Henry noted and edited my last sentence.

Comment: @Lesley Apparently, so I am told, so-called 'Christian atheists' are to be considered as within the spectrum of 'Christianity'. Wide is the gate and broad is the way which leadeth unto 'Christianity'. But within that wide and broad spectrum it is still true (for He says it is) that few actually find the gate and the way that lead unto Life. And even of those few who find it, many discover they are unable to actually enter it.Matthew 7:13 and 14.